# How to find out how long time the comment on facebook was hidden

Tags: api, facebook, comments, hide

I red the Facebook API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/comment
to find out if it is possible to use method to check how long time(day, clock) the comment was hidden before it is unhidden again. From the API I could only find a boolean, is_hidden. Maybe I am wrong.
Even if that is not possible to find out the time trough API, maybe there are other solutions to find out the time?
It will be of great help if someone have a suggestion to some kind of solution.
Br
Majja

Comment: The API does not provide that kind of information. At most you could pull the info in a regular interval, and then keep track of when it changes from hidden to visible or vice versa, on your end. (But with that you would probably be very likely to run into the API request limits soon.) Not sure what the actual use case for that would be to begin with though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer CBroe and possible solution, even it have its limitation, it gives me kind of hope that there is a solution!

Comment: The actual use case is to prove that the comment was hidden and is now unhidden. It has happened to one person that I know, he has been accused to lie (everyone telling he is crazy) and it is quite frustrating that it is not possible to prove that the person that hidded and now unhidded is the one laying and accusing poor guy. I really wanted to help him to prove he is not laying with help of my programming knowledge, but the function that could help dont exist; to find out the time the comment was hidden and unhidden.. Maybe Facebook servers have/save some kinde of info?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also saw that the other guy took away his comment and my friend was verry sad. And Yesterday the comments was back ??? and my friend is accused to lie :-(

Comment: No there is no API for that. There is no way to know if a comment was hidden before.